# Uniform convergence of a sequence of monotonic functions on closed intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

The problem is,

$f_n$ is monotonic on $\left [ a,b \right ] $ for all $n$, and $\left \{ f_n(x) \right \} $ converges to a continuous function $f$  on this closed interval, then the convergence is uniform.

Compared to [Dini's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem), the problem above change the condition of monotonicity on $n$ i.e. ($f_n \le f_{n+1},\; \forall x$) to that on $x$ i.e. ($f_n(x) < f_n(y) $ if $x<y$) and remove continuous of $f_n$.

My question is ,

1. Can this question be proved by **Heine–Borel theorem**(as in Dini's Theorem), or when(or what conditions does $f_n$ satisfy) can we use **Heine–Borel theorem** to prove uniform convergence on a closed intervel.
2. Is this proof below related to Heine–Borel theorem in some way?

---

This problem can be proved by this method,

Since $f \in C\left [ a,b \right ] $ then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\left [ a,b \right ] $ , thus $\forall \varepsilon >0,\; \exists\delta >0$, for $|x^{\prime}-x^{\prime\prime}|<\delta$, we have
$$
\mid f(x^{\prime})-f(x^{\prime\prime})\mid<\varepsilon.\quad (x^{\prime}, x^{\prime\prime} \in \left [ a,b \right ])
$$
Take the natural number $k$, s.t. $\frac{b-a}k<\delta $ then divide the interval into $k$ equal parts.
$$
a=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_k=b,\quad\Delta x_i=x_i-x_{i-1}=\frac{b-a}{k},\quad i=1,2,\cdots,k.
$$
Then,
\begin{aligned} 
  (1)&  \left|f\left(x_{i}\right)-f\left(x_{i-1}\right)\right|<\varepsilon ;\\
(2)&  \forall x \in\left[x_{i-1}, x_{i}\right],
\left|f(x)-f\left(x_{i}\right)\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2},\left|f(x)-f\left(x_{i-1}\right)\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2} ;\\
(3)&  \exists N_{i} ,   n>N_{i}  ,  \left|f_{n}\left(x_{i}\right)-f\left(x_{i}\right)\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}(i=0,1, \cdots, k) .\\
\end{aligned}

Let $N=\max\left\{N_{0},N_{1},\cdots,N_{k}\right\}$, $\forall x{\in}[x_{i-1},x_{i}]$ when $n>N$ we have
\begin{aligned}
&\mid f_n(x_{i-1})-f(x)\mid\leqslant\mid f_n(x_{i-1})-f(x_{i-1})\mid+
\mid f(x_{i-1})-f(x)\mid<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon,
\\
&\mid f_n(x_i)-f(x)\mid\leqslant\mid f_n(x_i)-f(x_i)\mid+
\mid f(x_i)-f(x)\mid<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon.
\end{aligned}

Then $\forall x \in[a, b] ,\exists i (1 \leqslant i \leqslant k) $, s.t. $x \in\left[x_{i-1}, x_{i}\right]$, By the monotonicity of $f_n$, we have
$$
\mid f_{n}(x)-f(x)\mid\leqslant\max\{\mid f_{n}(x_{i+1})-f(x)\mid,\mid f_{n}(x_{i})-f(x)\mid\}<\varepsilon.
$$

Comment: (Side comment, of no help for your question) Though seemingly due to Pólya, in France this is called [Dini's second theorem](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8mes_de_Dini#Deuxi%C3%A8me_th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Dini).